# Insertar en QuickBooks C# QODBC

Tags: c#, quicksort

Estoy tratando de insertar datos en la tabla "Transacción" de Quickbooks a través de `QODBC` pero recibo el siguiente error:

> System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: 'ERROR [42S00] [QODBC] No coinciden los tipos de datos para uno o más campos. Operando no válido para el operador: '

Recibo este mismo error usando `VBDEMO`, lo he intentado de varias maneras pero obtengo el mismo error.

Adjunto el código que uso en C #:

```
string entity = "MARTHA";
        string Account = "DISPONIBLE:EFECTIVO Y EQUIVALENTES AL EFEC:1112  BANCOS,2020-03-12";
        string amount ="400";
        string Memo = "Pruebas Migracion";
        DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime("2020/03/12");


        OdbcCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
        //comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Transaction(EntityRefFullName,AccountRefFullName,TxnDate,Amount,Memo) VALUES('"+ entity + "','" + Account + "','" + fecha + "','" + amount + "','" + Memo +  "')";
        comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Transaction(TxnDate,Amount) VALUES('" + date.ToShortDateString() + "'," + amount + ")";
        MessageBox.Show(comm.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString());
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que formatear la fecha para Quickbooks!

```
INSERT INTO ReceivePaymentLine(TotalAmount,TxnDate) VALUES (100.00,{d'01-26-2021'}
```